# SQL Server - output of XML node structure as per data

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

Requesting help for this: I have a requirement where the xml output needs to be in below desired format. The main hurdle is to get dynamic xml node `<Shares1_1>` which is Keyword 'Shares' concatenated with data in column Shares and ID.

Desired output:

[image]

Current table structure and data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TMP
CREATE TABLE #TMP(ID smallint, Shares VARCHAR(50), Name VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #TMP(ID, Shares, Name) 
VALUES (1,1,'John'), (2,1,'Tim'), (3,2,'Miles')

select * from #tmp
```

My attempt to get the output (not correct)

```
declare @xml xml 
select @xml =(
    
        select ID, Shares, Name
        from #tmp
        for xml path ('snap'),elements, xsinil, type
)
select @xml
```

Thanking you all in advance for looking into this.

Cheers.

Comment: The desired output XML structure is far from optimal. It is not a good idea to add running numbers to the XML element names: `<Shares1_1>` , `<Shares2_3>`, etc. It is better to make them as `<Share>`. If needed, you can add attributes to that XML element. And attribute values could hold dynamic values.

Comment: Agreed but that's the structure which is needed for a strange scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server is declarative by design.  You would have to use Dynamic SQL or a little string manipulation.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = ''

Select @S=@S+concat('<Shares',Shares,'_',ID,'>',B.XML,'</Shares',Shares,'_',ID,'>')
 From #tmp A
 Cross Apply ( Select A.* for XML path('') ) B(xml)

Declare @XML xml = convert(xml,concat('<Snap>',@S,'</Snap>'))
Select @XML
```

**Results**

```
<Snap>
  <Shares1_1>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Shares>1</Shares>
    <Name>John</Name>
  </Shares1_1>
  <Shares1_2>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Shares>1</Shares>
    <Name>Tim</Name>
  </Shares1_2>
  <Shares2_3>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Shares>2</Shares>
    <Name>Miles</Name>
  </Shares2_3>
</Snap>
```